# Scaling, normalization and grid search

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, normalization

I have a doubt about scaling and normalization of training data with grid search, where the score of each node is computed with k-fold cross validation. In particular, should training and scaling be independently computed for each k execution on each node, or only one time before the whole grid search?

In other words, should data be scaled and normalized separately for each candidate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always scale based on the *train data* only, otherwise - you are leaking "knowledge" to the *test set*.

Therefore, in K-fold CV you should do k normalizations.